# Perl access value from Hash Reference

Tags: perl, hashref, perl-hash

In my Perl code, I ended up having a hash reference like below. I would like to access an individual element from it.  I tried multiple ways, but I was not able to fetch it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my %h={'one'=>1,'two'=>2};
print Dumper($h{'one'});
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = undef;
```

Comment: _Always_ `use strict; use warnings;`! If you did, you’d have seen something like `Reference found where even-sized list expected`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [parentheses](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata#List-value-constructors) to construct your hash, not braces:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = ('one'=>1, 'two'=>2);
print Dumper($h{'one'});
```

Braces are used to construct a hash reference.

Also, add `use warnings;`, which would have generated a message that there was a problem with your code.

---

Or, if you really wanted a hashref:

```
my $h = {'one'=>1, 'two'=>2};
print "$h->{one}\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

What you've (accidentally) done there, is to create a hash with a key that is a stringified hash reference and a value that is `undef`. And `perldoc perlref` has a section called [WARNING: Don't use references as hash keys](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#WARNING:-Don%27t-use-references-as-hash-keys).